# Averaging every 10 rows of one column within a dataframe, pulling every tenth item from the others?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have the following sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'depth': list(range(0, 21)),

                   'time': list(range(0, 21)),

                   'metric': random.choices(range(10), k=21)})
df
Out[65]: 
      depth  time  metric
0       0     0       2
1       1     1       3
2       2     2       8
3       3     3       0
4       4     4       8
5       5     5       9
6       6     6       5
7       7     7       1
8       8     8       6
9       9     9       6
10     10    10       7
11     11    11       2
12     12    12       7
13     13    13       0
14     14    14       6
15     15    15       0
16     16    16       5
17     17    17       6
18     18    18       9
19     19    19       6
20     20    20       8
```

I want to average every ten rows of the "metric" column (preserving the first row as is) and pulling the tenth item from the depth and time columns. For example:

```
      depth  time  metric
0       0     0       2
10     10    10       5.3
20     20    20       4.9
```

I know that groupby is usually used in these situations, but I do not know how to tweak it to get my desired outcome:

```
df[['metric']].groupby(df.index //10).mean()
Out[66]: 
   metric
0     4.8
1     4.8
2     8.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BENY's answer is on the right track but not quite right. Should be:

```
df.groupby((df.index+9)//10).agg({'depth':'last','time':'last','metric':'mean'})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `rolling` with `reindex+ffill`

```
df.rolling(10).mean().reindex(df.index[::10]).fillna(df)
```

---

```
    depth  time  metric
0     0.0   0.0     2.0
10    5.5   5.5     5.3
20   15.5  15.5     4.9
```

Or to match output for depth and time:

```
out = (df.assign(metric=df['metric'].rolling(10).mean()
         .reindex(df.index[::10]).fillna(df['metric']))
         .dropna(subset=['metric']))

print(out)

    depth  time  metric
0       0     0     2.0
10     10    10     5.3
20     20    20     4.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `agg`

```
g = df.index.isin(df.index[::10]).cumsum()[::-1]
df.groupby(g).agg({'depth':'last','time':'last','metric':'mean'})
Out[263]: 
   depth  time  metric
1     20    20     4.9
2     10    10     5.3
3      0     0     2.0
```